# Illegal characters in path

Tags: java, genexus

Le hago un build with this only a cualquier objeto de mi kb, y me da error: The work item caused an exception, see the inner exception for details error: Illegal characters in path. Failed: Build With This Only.

Cual puede ser el problema?

Gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿En algún momento estás haciendo referencia a una ruta? Deberías revisar que no contenga ninguno de los siguientes caracteres:  \ / : * ? " < > | # { } % ~ &” ni tampoco un espacio.